# Is it bad practice to use public static nested classes in Java?

Tags: java

I'm making an API that has an abstract class `A`. In addition to users of my API creating their own classes extending `A` I want to have a number of default classes that also extend `A` that users can access. Is it considered bad practice for me to make a class `B` with numerous classes nested in it like `public static class ExampleA extends A`?

Comment: Very broad question. Need an example. But if it's bad practice, I'd say probably yes. What benefit do you hope to get by having multiple concrete implementations in a single file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when you nest classes you do that to *say* that the nested class is only used by the wrapping class. Have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for information. You should think of it mainly as one of many tools to logically organize code and express how classes are related.

In your case, you provide some implementations for an abstract class that are supposed to be used by the other programmers. This is widely done in many frameworks to provide the developers with default implementations. Those implementations are inherently **not** supposed to be used just by one class.

In your case, you don't want to nest default implementations in a class `B` because those can be used elsewhere. If you want to organize your class structure you should rather think about packages.